# Varying outputs with a synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a multi-threaded and synchronized incrementing function but it doesn't show a consistent output :-

```
$ java Main
count: 999883

$ java Main
count: 1000000

$ java Main
count: 999826

$ java Main
count: 1000000

$ java Main
count: 1000000
```

I have a synchronized counter :-

```
public class Counter {
    public int count;
    synchronized void inc() {
        count = count+1;
    }
    int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

A thread class that is initialized with a counter object and increments it 1000 times :-

```
public class CountPrimesRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Counter c;

    public CountPrimesRunnable(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            c.inc();
    }
}
```

And the Main class that creates 1000 threads at a time :-

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfThreads = 1000;
        Thread[] worker = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
        Counter c = new Counter();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            worker[i] = new Thread(new CountPrimesRunnable(c));

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            worker[i].start();

        System.out.println("count: " + c.count);
    }
}
```

What is it that I am missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but it doesn't show a consistent output :-

That's because, it's not sure from your code that `main` thread will always finish after all the other threads are done with their job. In some cases where you get result less than `1000000`, are the cases, where some threads still execute after the main thread has finished.

You can invoke [`Thread#join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)  method on each of the newly created thread to make sure that the `main` method waits for all those threads to die, before continuing execution after for loop.

So, you will have to add another for loop to invoke `join` on each of the threads started, and also you can avoid using the 2nd for loop, by merging it with the first one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    worker[i] = new Thread(new CountPrimesRunnable(c));
    worker[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    worker[i].join();
}
```

When you invoke `join` on a `Thread A` from inside a `Thread B`, the `Thread B` will continue the further execution only after `Thread A` dies.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit . One more q. When the main thread calls join() for worker[0] does it immediately start waiting. If yes then what about starting the remaining workers. If no then how does it know when to start waiting.

Comment: @Himanshu. It starts waiting for `worker[0]` thread as soon as it calls `join` on it and when `worker[0]` finishes, it goes on with starting other threads `worker[1], worker[2], and so on`, and waits for them sequentially, as the for loop is executing.

Comment: So, in other words, you can say that, thread `worker[i]` waits for thread `worker[j]` if `i > j`.

Comment: Using join() serializes the starting of the threads. Therefore, there is no thread concurrency happening.  If you remove the synchronized keyword from inc() method you still get a correct answer when using the join() solution.  This indicates the threads are running serially.  The correct solution is to wait for all threads to stop before reading count using isAlive();

Comment: @ChuckFricano. Ah! I should have used a different loop for joining to avoid sequential running of threads. Silly mistake.

Comment: @ChuckFricano IMO even though joining is there but without synchronized there is no guarantee that the value of the count will be up to date.

Comment: @RohitJain - Your updated solution runs risk of joining a dead thread.  That may or may not be okay.  I would use isAlive() to ensure all threads are dead before reading count.

Comment: @NarendraPathai. Well, that is also true and a crucial point to consider, but in this case, that will not happen, since the `count` is being read by `main` method at the end of all threads. So, that will always give the last updated count. That is the effect of calling `join`.

Comment: @NarendraPathai - I was just pointing out that removing synchronized does not cause a problem when using Rohit's original join() solution.  Rohit changed the solution to include two loops which does allow for concurrency.  I'm just not sure about joining a dead thread.  I think it is better to wait for all threads to die using isAlive().

Comment: @ChuckFricano. Exactly. That is what I'm saying.

Comment: @RohitJain - Unfortunately, your 3rd solution does not guarantee that the thread is still alive after you call isAlive() and before you call join().   The thread could die between the two calls.  Again, calling join() on a dead thread maybe okay - I  don't know.  I

Comment: @ChuckFricano. Yeah it's ok to call `join` on dead thread. It will return immediately. So it won't be any problem. So, I don't need to test for `isAlive` before hand.

Comment: @ChuckFricano I am not sure what you mean - `join()` on a dead thread will simply return immediately. I don't think there is a need to check for `isAlive` at all.

Comment: @RohitJain (and assylias) - I was not sure of any problems from joining a dead thread so if there are no concerns, I tend to agree with Rohits 2nd solution. Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Counter {
    public int count;
    synchronized void inc() {
        count = count+1;
    }

    //this method must also be synchronized for establishing the happens-before relationship
    synchronized int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Only if both the get and set are synchronized **on the same lock**, you are guaranteed that you will see the latest value.

Also you need to call join and wait for all threads to complete execution.